# Self adjoint operator property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two self adjoint operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \gamma)$, suppose the spectral measure $\mu, \gamma$ are absolutely continuous. Show that $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent.

I don't see how abs. continuous can help proving the claim. Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that $\mu,\gamma$ are positive measures, since you consider the $L^2$ spaces w.r.t. these. But you also call $\mu,\nu$ **spectral measures**, which would be projector valued measures. Could you clarify this?

Comment: The question professor give is stated as is. i need to ask him first. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi = d\gamma/d\mu$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative, then for any $f \geq 0$ we have
$$
\int fd\gamma = \int f\varphi d\mu \qquad (\ast)
$$
In addition to absolute continuity, you also need the fact that
$$
\varphi \in L^{\infty}(\mu)
$$
The proof is in the following steps :
- Since $\mu$ and $\gamma$ are both positive measures, $\varphi \geq 0$ a.e. $[\mu]$
- Define $U : L^2(\gamma) \to L^2(\mu)$ by
$$
f \mapsto \sqrt{\varphi}f
$$
By $(\ast)$ it follows that
$$
\|U(f)\|_2 = \|f\|_2
$$
so $U$ is an isometry.
- Now do the same with
$$
\psi := d\gamma/d\mu
$$
to get an operator
$$
V : L^2(\mu) \to L^2(\gamma)
$$
- Check that this satisfies both $V = U^{-1}$ and $V = U^{\ast}$ (once again, using $(\ast)$)
- Finally check that $U$ conjugates $A$ to $B$ (or rather, the multiplication operators corresponding to $A$ and $B$)

Comment: For Radon-Nikodym to be applicable. You need a function $\varphi$ that satisfies the equality $(\ast)$

Comment: also,why do you need $\varphi$ to be $L^\infty$.

Comment: To make the operator $U$ well-defined. Multiplication operators are bounded on $L^2$ only of the function is $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: Just the last thing, to see $A=UBU^*$ and start by computing $UBU^*(f)=\sqrt{\varphi}B(\sqrt{\psi}f)$. How to get $A(f)$ from the computation. We don't know any relationship between $A$ and $B$ yet

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are both unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $x$ on their respective $L^2$ spaces. This unitary implements an equivalence between those multiplication operators.

Comment: Ok, where is this fact from? Is there a name for this theorem. I read through Simon and reed's book, but I found you need $A$ and $B$ to be bounded and with cyclic vector for them to be unitarily equivalent to mulitplication by $x$.

Comment: We know that $A$ is $B$ are unitarily equivalent to multiplication by a measurable function